# How to create a Jquery array object

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I have to pass values to highChart in following format

```
data: [
     ['Firefox',   45.0],
     ['IE',       26.8],
]
```

I have the values in a table something like this

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2">
            <div align="left">Expenditure in, or on behalf of, Scotland </div>            
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
        <td>Public sector debt interest</td>
        <td><?php echo $x ?>></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
        <td>Public sector debt interest</td>
        <td><?php echo $x ?>></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I trying to create array from the table like this but its not working

```
$('.row').each(function (i) {
    var data = [];
    $(this).find('td').each(function (j, v) {
        if (j == 0)
            var label = $(this).html();
        else {
            var val = $(this).html();
            data[label] = val;
        } 
    });
});
```

Can any one please help me out where I am doing the mistake

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data structure you're trying to create is an array containing arrays. It is a native JS construct and has nothing to do with jQuery. The issue you have is that you're trying to create an array item by providing a key/value pair, which is fine for objects but won't work here.

Firstly, the parent array needs to be defined outside the `each`. Then you need to create a new array for each row and push it to the parent array. You don't need to loop over the `td` elements as you need to get both at the same time to create the array item. Try this:

```
var data = [];
$('.row').each(function (i) {
    var label = $(this).find('td').eq(0).text(); // get value of the first td as a number
    var value = parseFloat($(this).find('td').eq(1).text()); // and the second
    data.push([label, value]); // add the new item to the array
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/n48w6rt3/)

Comment: I tried to implement the array into the script but it trhows error 

http://jsfiddle.net/n48w6rt3/1/

Comment: Your HTML is incorrect as the `table` is inside a `script` tag

Comment: thank you very much , I tried to add the actual content of the table , Since you were changing the Label also into Float val the names were not appearing , I changes that to normal string , But the size of the chart became very small can you help me fix this please

http://jsfiddle.net/n48w6rt3/3/

Comment: @Vikram ah yes, sorry my bad :D

Comment: also I am trying to add another half of the chart using similar table , is it possible to do in the same script ?

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring the variable `data` inside the callback function. That means that it will be recreated for each row, and that it won't be available once you looped through all the rows. Declare it outside the loop.

You put the values in the variable in the form of a property, not an array item. That means that the array is still empty. Create an array, and add to the array `data`.

You declare the variable `label` inside the callback function for the inner `each`, so it will go away and be recreated when the callback is called the second time for the second cell. Declare `label` outside that loop to keep the value between the calls.

The value should be numeric in the result, not a string, so you should parse it.

```
var data=[];
$('.row').each(function (i) {
  var label, val;
  $(this).find('td').each(function (j, v) {
    if (j == 0) {
      label = $(this).html();
    } else {
      val = parseFloat($(this).html());
      data.push([ label, val ]);
    } 
  });
});
```